# How do you fix TouchableOpacity getting blocked by SafeAreaView

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I am making an app from React Native, and I've added a `<TouchableOpacity>` with an image inside of it. I added an onPressIn prop to run some code when the image gets pressed. I gave the image a `top: 10` but whenever I click it, there's only a 10% chance of it working.

I tried moving it down and I noticed that when the image is not close to the `<SafeAreaView>` then I can click it and it works 99.9% of the time. I was wondering how I could make it so I can have it as high up on the screen as possible, but still have the onPressIn work.

Here is the code if it helps :)

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StatusBarHeight = Constants.statusBarHeight;

var onPressSettings=() => {
    alert("KING KOVID");
}

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={Styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPressIn={() => {onPressSettings();}} activeOpacity={0.5}>
                <Image
                    source={require('../assets/app_icons/settings.png')} 
                    style={{ width: 40, height: 40, position: 'absolute', right: 20, top: 10}}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    resizeMethod="resize"
                />
        </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 30}}>SocialSquare</Text>
            <Text>Home Screen</Text>
            <Image
                source={require('../assets/doge.gif')}
                resizeMode = 'contain'
                style={{
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                }}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default HomeScreen;

const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 25,
        backgroundColor: '#08F1ED',
    },
});
```

Comment: you could increase the zIndex value of the TouchableOpacity

Answer (score 0):

try increasing zIndex style on the TouchableOpacity... I got the answer from nazmul from the comments but i really thought of that before i read nazmul's comment so Cheers!